# Datetime value extracted from a Form (php)

Tags: php, datetime

My table ("list") contains one field ("exam_date") of type: "datetime".
I want users to insert,  via a Form, a value of datetime type so i can insert it into that table.
I want to display a default value in the input field:  present date& time.
My code goes like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
<head>
<title>Show Date</title>
<meta charset=utf-8>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$dbcon = @mysqli_connect ('xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx') 
OR die ('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error () ); 
mysqli_set_charset($dbcon, 'utf8');
if (isset($_POST['exam_date']))
{
$myDate = trim($_POST['exam_date']);
$q = "INSERT INTO list (exam_date) VALUES ($myDate)"; 
$result = @mysqli_query ($dbcon, $q);   
?>
<form action="to_forum.php" method="post">
<input id="exam_date" name="exam_date" type="datetime" 
 value="<?php echo date(); ?>">
<input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I inserted "14-2-2014". A record was added but with a blank date value. The input field didn't show any default value !
Anyone could please suggest how to make the above code show a default date  and time value and make it properly added to the table?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's several problems here.

- You don't close your `if` condition.
- You don't format your date before inserting into the database.

---

```
if (isset($_POST['exam_date']))
{
    $myDate = trim($_POST['exam_date']);
    $newDate = new DateTime($myDate); //create new datetime object//
    $myDate = $newDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $q = "INSERT INTO list (exam_date) VALUES ($myDate)"; 
    $result = @mysqli_query ($dbcon, $q);
} //missing//
```

Answer (score 0):

change you `INSERT` statement to

```
 $q = "INSERT INTO list (exam_date) VALUES (STR_TO_DATE($myDate,'%d-%m-%Y'))";
```